# how to save battery life using requestLocationUpdates/removeLocationUpdates

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making a simple location reminder where the user picks an address on the map and I create a proximityAlert with that.

My first thought was to only search for a new location if it's even possible to reach the destination in that time frame. 
F.e. if the target is 80 miles away there's no point in constantly querying the location since it will be about an hour to reach with a car.
I found another approach [here](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~demirbas/publications/proximity.pdf)
which only gets location updates when driving.

1. I would like to get some input about these two approaches. Would that really save battery life over using the proximityAlert?
2. If I do those calculations myself do I have to implement my own version of proximityAlert()?
3. The LocationIntentService which receives the location updates is a separate class: how would I get access to the location client to removeUpdates and/or requestLocationUpdates?
4. Do I have to use the AlarmManager to wake the location updates?

I'm pretty much stuck in the onHandleIntent() method: I'm not sure what to do there. I'm glad for any inputs

```
    public class MyMapActivity extends Activity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener, 
       OnMarkerClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener, 
       GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
       GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
    {

       private LocationClient mLocationClient;
       private PendingIntent mPendingIntent = null;
       private LocationRequest mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
          .setInterval(5000)         // 5 seconds
          .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
          .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


       @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gmaps);

            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater()));
            map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
            map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
            String locationProvider = findBestLocationProvider();
            if(locationProvider != null) {
                  mMyLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), LocationIntentService.class);
            intent.putExtra(LOCATION_KEY, mMyLocation);
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
       }

       @Override
       public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected()");
            if(mLocationClient != null) {
                mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mPendingIntent);
            }
       }

       @Override
       public void onDisconnected() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDisconnected()");
       }
    }
```

The service:

```
  public class LocationIntentService  extends IntentService {

     private Location mLocation = null;

     @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
         Log.d(tag, "caught an intent");

         if(intent.hasExtra(MyMapActivity.LOCATION_KEY)) {
         Location loc = (Location) intent.getExtras().get(MyMapActivity.LOCATION_KEY);
         Log.d(tag, "onHandleIntent(): new location: " + loc.toString());

           // do calculation here.
           // how would I get access to the location client to removeUpdates and/or requestLocationUpdates
          // remove locationUpdates and start Alarm to start locationUpdates in X minutes
         mLocation = loc;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the Geofencing library also provided by Google Play Services? http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Isn't that similar to using addProximityAlert()? I can't control when the location services search for locations. Or did I misunderstand that? there doesn't seem to be a lot of information..

Comment: after reading a bit more about this new API I will give it a try. I guess the geofencing library already takes care of the battery issue.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am looking into issues of an app (I adopted) regarding Geofencing. Are your experiences with it good? The app uses IntentService to do the trigger. I'm going to give BroadCastReceiver a try here. Any experience that this will indeed fix issues of missed events?

Comment: The Geofencing API and an IntentService work great together.